# Fields of definition of conjugates

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, rational-points

Let $k$ be a field, not necessarily algebraically closed, $G$ an affine group scheme over $k$, $H$ a subgroup of $G$, and $N$ a normal subgroup of $H$, none of them assumed to be smooth.  Suppose that $g \in G(\overline k)$ is such that the image of $g$ in $(G/H)(\overline k)$ is contained in $(G/H)(k)$.  Is $g N_{\overline k} g^{-1}$ defined over $k$?

By Galois descent, it suffices to assume that $k$ is separably closed.  Then, if $H$ is smooth, we have that the fibre of $G \to G/H$ over $g$ is smooth, hence contains a rational point, so that the desired result is clear.  Thus the problem is only of interest if $H$ is neither smooth, nor even contained in a smooth subgroup of $\operatorname{Norm}_G(N)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, and affineness is unnecessary. We'll assume that $G$ is locally of finite type (as I imagine was intended), but this is not essential. In brief, the proof proceeds by using fppf descent in place of Galois descent; this will involve working over a base slightly more general than a field (i.e., a finite algebra over a field). See Bosch–Lütkebohmert–Raynaud, *[Néron models](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-51438-8)*, 6.1/6 for the relevant descent statements. If $X$ is a $k$-scheme and $k'$ is a $k$-algebra, we will write $X_{k'} = X \times_{\operatorname{Spec} k} \operatorname{Spec} k'$. By SGA3, Exp. VI_A, Thm. 3.2, the scheme quotient $G/H$ represents the quotient in the sense of fppf sheaves, so the meaning of $G/H$ is unambiguous.

By assumption, $g \in G(\overline{k})$ has image $[g]$ in $(G/H)(\overline{k})$ which lies in $(G/H)(k)$. Since $G$ is locally of finite type, there is a finite (not necessarily separable) extension $k'$ of $k$ such that $g \in G(k')$. Since $G/H$ is a sheaf for the fppf topology, the sequence of maps
$$
1 \to (G/H)(k) \to (G/H)(k') \rightrightarrows (G/H)(k' \otimes_k k')
$$
is exact. In particular, if $i_1, i_2: k' \to k' \otimes_k k'$ are the two natural ring maps, then $i_1^*[g] = i_2^*[g]$. Moreover, the fact that $G/H$ represents the fppf sheaf quotient implies that there is a faithfully flat, finite type ring map $f: k' \otimes_k k' \to k''$ and $h'' \in H(k'')$ such that $f^*i_1^*g \cdot h'' = f^*i_2^*g$. Since $N$ is a $k$-scheme, we have $i_1^*N_{k'} = i_2^*N_{k'}$. We have $h''N_{k''} (h'')^{-1} = N_{k''}$ since $N$ is normal in $H$ by hypothesis, and thus
$$
(i_1^*g) N_{k' \otimes_k k'} (i_1^*g)^{-1} = (i_2^*g) N_{k' \otimes_k k'} (i_2^*g)^{-1}
$$
since this may be checked after pulling back via $f$. This means that $i_1^*(gN_{k'}g^{-1}) = i_2^*(gN_{k'}g^{-1})$, and thus by fppf descent for affine morphisms (e.g., closed immersions), we see that $gN_{k'}g^{-1}$ is the base change to $k'$ of a closed subscheme of $G_{k'}$.

Comment: I've always been afraid of the term "fppf descent", so knowing a place to look for it (even if it is in BLR, which has itself always frightened me), as well as having this walk-through of how to use it in what is for me a comparatively concrete case, is probably even more valuable to me than knowing the answer to my specific question.  Thank you! \\ By the way, `\operatorname` takes care of operator spacing, so you can just use `\operatorname{Spec} k` in place of `\mathrm{Spec}\,k`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: I'm glad it helps, and thanks for the tip! Working with group schemes as fppf sheaves makes it possible to treat them like ordinary groups in many situations (as long as you're willing to extend the base ring past fields sometimes, as above), and fppf descent is a nice tool to ensure rationality of any construction in the end. It's unfortunate that the written references for this useful tool (e.g., SGA1, BLR, Stacks Project) tend to have such fearsome reputations.

Comment: There's a chance that I might wind up using this in a paper.  In case I do, would you be willing to tell me your full name so that I can credit you?  You can find my e-mail on my web page, linked in my [profile](https://mathoverflow.net/users/2383/lspice).  (Sorry for the indirection—hoping not to lure any spammers.)

Comment: I find it easier to read [Milne - Algebraic groups](https://doi.org/10.1017/9781316711736) than SGA, so I'll point out for anyone else in the same boat that the exactness of $(G/H)(k) \to (G/H)(k') \rightrightarrows (G/H)(k' \otimes_k k')$ is Lemma 5.9 (but I think you are using only the weaker statement that the compositions $(G/H)(k) \to (G/H)(k') \rightrightarrows (G/H)(k' \otimes_k k')$ are the same, which follows just from functoriality of $G/H$), and what Milne calls being "fat" (used to produce $k''$ and $h''$) is Proposition 5.7.